# plsql dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype change xml tag format

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

We have been using SQL developer's database export function to create some data dump files. The file format looks like this:

> ```
> <?xml version='1.0'  encoding='Cp1252' ?>
> <RESULTS>
>   <ROW>
>       <COLUMN NAME="A_ID"><![CDATA[3]]></COLUMN>
>       <COLUMN NAME="B_ID"><![CDATA[A3V09LJAF]]></COLUMN>
>   </ROW>
>   <ROW>
>       <COLUMN NAME="A_ID"><![CDATA[5]]></COLUMN>
>       <COLUMN NAME="B_ID"><![CDATA[4FAPU90FSD]]></COLUMN>
>   </ROW>
> </RESULTS>
> ```

But recently the management decided to automate the process, one option is to use spool:

```
SPOOL 'D:\SOME\PATH\TO\DIR\1.XML'
SELECT dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('SELECT A_ID, B_ID FROM SOME_TABLE') FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF;
```

However the dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype gives different tag type in the exported file:

> ```
>  <ROWSET>
>    <ROW>
>      <A_ID>3</A_ID>
>      <B_ID>A3V09LJAF</B_ID>
>    </ROW>
>    <ROW>
>      <A_ID>5</A_ID>
>      <B_ID>4FAPU90FSD</B_ID>
>    </ROW>
>  </ROWSET>
> ```

Is there a way to change the TAG format and add the CDATA to be exact as SQL developer export file?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an easier way would be use SQLcl, which has the same "engine" as SQL Developer.  Thus in SQLcl you would do this

```
SQL> SET SQLFORMAT XML
SQL> SELECT * FROM emp WHERE deptno = 20;
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF8' ?>
<RESULTS>
        <ROW>
                <COLUMN NAME="EMPNO"><![CDATA[7369]]></COLUMN>
                <COLUMN NAME="ENAME"><![CDATA[SMITH]]></COLUMN>
                <COLUMN NAME="JOB"><![CDATA[CLERK]]></COLUMN>
                <COLUMN NAME="MGR"><![CDATA[7902]]></COLUMN>
                <COLUMN NAME="HIREDATE"><![CDATA[17-DEC-80]]></COLUMN>
                <COLUMN NAME="SAL"><![CDATA[800]]></COLUMN>
                <COLUMN NAME="COMM"><![CDATA[]]></COLUMN>
                <COLUMN NAME="DEPTNO"><![CDATA[20]]></COLUMN>
        </ROW>
```

Download SQLcl from here

https://www.oracle.com/au/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html

Comment: Thank you. It works great. One question, after testing, for the same export job, SQL developer took 12 seconds, but SQLcl took 35 sec (login process not counted). Is there a way to optimize?

Comment: double check your arraysize setting for sqlcl. That is the most common cause. Bump it up to (say) 200-500